# How To Inherit DataTable And Add Features To DataColumn in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

How can i inherit DataTable And DataColumn and Add some of Features or Properties

```
public class CustomDataTable : DataTable
{ 
    public class CDataColumn : DataColumn
    {
      add properties or features here 
    }

    private enum ColumnFormat { Text, Qty, Amount, Date }
}
```

I Want to inherit DataColumn and Add property ColumnFormat In DataTable .
Thanks alot